# Add differing CSS rules to a set of generated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to loop and add several multicolored spans to a div container. To do this efficiently, I simply alter the `css`, instead of adding a new color class to the element:

```
      var colorEn =  ["RoyalBlue", "LawnGreen", "red", "orange", "yellow", "black", "white", "MediumOrchid"];
      for ( i = 0; i < colorEn.length; i++ ) {
            var $span = $('<span />').attr('class', 'coloratorSquare');     
               $span.css({background : colorEn[i]});
               $("#colorator").append($span);
      }
```

Generating, for example:

`<span class="coloratorSquare active" style="background: rgb(65, 105, 225);"></span>`

Then, when I select (click) a certain span, it will change color to Silver show it has been selected, and set all other sibling spans back to their original colors. Here's a snippet:

```
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
```

The problem is, if I alter the `css` of the span elements (`$span.css(...)`), it doesn't apply the `CSS` changes on add/remove class. But if I comment out changing the css of the span, the multiple colors aren't added, but the `active` class add/removal of selected/deselected span changes colors as expected:

`// $span.css({background : colorEn[i]});`

CSS:

```
        .active {
            background-color: Silver;
            color: black;
        }
```

I would simply not alter `.css` of a span at all, but don't think it makes sense to add classes to each span during generation, and have to add `CSS` class rules for each color to replicate that `.css` functionality.

**My question:** How can I add multiple different css rules (ex: multicolors) to randomly generated elements without a) having to generate all those rules manually in the CSS file, and b) altering the `.css` with jQuery such that it causes problems with adding/removing CSS class rules.

Sorry if this is unclear.

Thanks!

Comment: You should definitely manipulate with classes, not css directly.

Comment: You change the CSS directly, and then you expect the rest to "change back to the original color" when one span is clicked.. You changed that original color, when you altered the CSS directly. Of course it's not gonna change back to an original color, you removed that color and replaced it with another. (Or maybe I'm not getting what you're trying to say) ... Also, waht *dfsq* said

Comment: Styles applied to elements take precedence over classes.  If you want to do it this way you probably need to change the styles instead of adding and removing classes, which I know will be more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use `!important` on the silver color to have it override the locally set attributes of your elements, but that technique is frowned upon.

My recommendation is to consider the circumstances; if this is not throwaway code, then it usually makes better sense to set classes on the elements instead of directly manipulating their style attribute. If it's something you need for a mockup then by all means slap `!important` on it and move on.